# The problem about printf function to "output float with %d" in C

Tags: c, printf, ieee-754

I am a newbie to the C language. When I was learning floating point numbers today, I found the following problems.

```
float TEST= 3.0f;
printf("%x\n",TEST);
printf("%d\n",TEST);
```

first output:

```
9c9e82a0
-1667333472
```

second output:

```
61ea32a0
1642738336
```

As shown above, each execution will output different results. I have checked a lot of IEEE 754 format and still don't understand the reasons. I would like to ask if anyone can explain or provide keywords for me to study, thank you.

-----------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------

Thank you for your replies. I know how to print IEEE 754 bit pattern. However, as Nate Eldredge, chux-Reinstate Monica said, using %x and %d in printf is undefined behavior. If there is no floating point register in our device, how does it work ? Is this described in the C99 specification?

Comment: This is undefined behavior in C.  If you want to inspect the hex representation of a `float`, you need to do something like `memcpy` it into a `uint32_t`.

Comment: In particular, on many implementations, float and integer parameters are passed in separate registers, so you're printing out some value leftover in the integer register that has nothing at all to do with the `3.0f` that's in a floating point register.

Comment: Fan Harry, Use `%g`, `%e`, `%a`, or `%f` to print a floating point value, not , `%x`, `%d`.  The later two result in _undefined behavior_.   `%a` will help with seeing the IEEE 754 format.

Comment: There are both wrong: please try `printf("%f\n",TEST);`

Comment: "If there is no floating point register in our device, how does it work ?"  "Is this described in the C99 specification?" --> C does not specify that detail. It is up to the implementation.

Comment: Fan Harry, have you tried `printf("%a\n",TEST);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, i already tried printf("%a\n",TEST), It can help me see the exponent and mantissa field of IEEE 754 more easily, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, when you call a function with the "wrong kind" (wrong type) of argument, an automatic conversion happens.  For example, if you write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

printf("%f\n", sqrt(144));
```

this works just fine.  The compiler knows (from the function prototype in `<math.h>`) that the `sqrt` function expects an argument of type `double`.  You passed it the `int` value `144`, so the compiler automatically converted that `int` to `double` before passing it to `sqrt`.

But this is *not* true for the `printf` function.  `printf` accepts arguments of many different types, and as long as each argument is right for the particular `%` format specifier it goes with in the format string, it's fine.  So if you write

```
double f = 3.14;
printf("%f\n", f);
```

it works.  But if you write

```
printf("%d\n", f);     /* WRONG */
```

it doesn't work.  `%d` expects an `int`, but you passed a `double`.  In this case (because `printf` is special), there's no good way for the compiler to insert an automatic conversion.  So, instead, it just fails to work.

And when it "fails", it really *fails*.  You don't even necessarily get anything "reasonable", like an integer representing the bit pattern of the IEEE-754 floating-point number you thought you passed.  If you want to inspect the bit pattern of a `float` or `double`, you'll have to do that another way.

---

If what you really wanted to do *was* to see the bits and bytes making up a `float`, here's a completely different way:

```
float test = 3.14;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&test;
int i;
printf("bytes in %f:", test);
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(test); i++) printf(" %02x", p[i]);
printf("\n");
```

There are some issues here with *byte ordering* ("endianness"), but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

To print hex (ie how it is represented in the memory) representation of the float:

```
    float TEST= 3.0f;
    int y=0;

    memcpy(&y, &TEST, sizeof(y));
    printf("%x\n",y);
    printf("%d\n",y);
```

or

```
    union
    {
        float TEST;
        int   y;
    }uf = {.y = 0};

    uf.TEST = 3.0f;
    printf("\n%x\n",(unsigned)uf.y);
    printf("%d\n",uf.y);
```

Both examples assuming `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(int)` (if they are not equal I need to zero the integer)

And the result (same for both):

```
40400000
1077936128
```

As you can see it is completely different from your one.
https://godbolt.org/z/Kr61x6Kv3

Comment: assuming the size of a float is equal or smaller than the size of the integer.